# Add index column on listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm using WPF, I have a window with a listview which is binded to an ObservableCollection.

So It's looks like that:

```
public ObservableCollection<Task> TaskList { get; set; }
```

Task being a model

```
public class Task 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   .... 
}
```

The XAML of the ListView.ItemTemplate:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <WrapPanel>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </WrapPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I cannot use the Id because items in the collection can be deleted or sorted, I need the index in the collection (with update if the collection get changed).

I would like to find a way to add an "index column" to the listview, so the index of the Task in the ObservableCollection would be before the name in every row (see below).

|   0 Task
|   1 TaskTest
|   2 OtherTask
|   3 LastTask

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it's not that easy to add index :(

If I was You, I'll add a property to item, that is shown in Your listview. That property would be filled with ViewModel and incremented. But if You sort or delete it should be rewritten.

You can also try making a property inside Your ViewModel like:

```
private int counter;
public int Index
{
    get
    {
        counter++;
        return counter;
    }
}
```

and Bind it to each element using RelativeSource FindAncestor. but again - it should be refreshed on collectionChange

Comment: Unfortunately that's what i thought, there is no *magic way* to do that :( But thanks for you answer that's what I will use.

Answer (score 0):

try this,crate a view model

```
public class TaskViewModel : Task
{
    private int _Index;

    public int Index
    {
        get { return _Index; }
        set { _Index = value; }
    }
}
```

ItemTemplate:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,4,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

code behind:

```
TaskViewModel vm = new TaskViewModel();
vm.Id = 0;
vm.Index = 1;
vm.Name = "sad";
TaskList.Add(vm);
```